# Opcache, APC or Session.Upload_Progress for Multiple File Uploads from single File Input

Tags: javascript, php, session, apc, opcache

I have few questions regarding Multiple File uploads in PHP. I have this single File Input as

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" />
```

1)**Question 1:** Is it possible to track Upload progress with Opcache? if yes then where can I find a good article? or what can be code for that?

2)**Question 2:** Is it possible to upload multiple files from single file input element and track upload progress of each individual file seperately with Session.Upload_Progress? if yes then what can be code for that? Any good article?

3)**Question 3:** If Opcache and Session.Upload_progress both cannot be used for tracking multiple files from single file input element and track upload progress of each individual file seperately  then should I use APC with PHP 5.5.3 or greater?

I read a long list of other articles but none of them described what I am upto. Currently I am working with this IBM article and following its code. I followed the same code from [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-v525/)

I can make some code with APC to perform multiple file uploads from single input element but again the question no 3 comes in.

So, basically how can I make a code to upload multiple files with single file input element and track upload progress of each file individually? It doesn't matter what to use it can be done either with Opcache or APC or Session.Upload_Progress.

Comment: These are really nice questions. It would be even nicer if you show what you tried already. I know tracking the file upload progress is possible through checking the filesize of the temp file created on upload but there need to be configuration/setup done because PHP reacts after the temp file has finished, but it needs to process during the upload..

Comment: Thanks @DanFromGermany I have provided the link of the Code i have followed and with that many other articles but all are about single file or if multiple files then using multiple file inputs not from single

Answer (score 0):

if using html5 isn't a problem for you:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-reading-files - reading multiple files from 1 input

http://www.matlus.com/html5-file-upload-with-progress/ - upload progress bar

Comment: I have already gone through your said articles but none of them describes what I am asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using APC session upload progress, because it tracks a single file at a time. See: http://php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.rfc1867

If you are using PHP 5.4.0 and above, check out this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php

If you prefer an easier way, I would recommend this: http://www.plupload.com/. It works very well.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have already gone through your said articles but none of them describes what I am asking for. And using external plugin is not a solution in my case.

Comment: although your answer is not exactly the one i was looking for but I found my answers of all my questions by myself and will post it soon but as you tried to provide some good links I would like to award you this bounty. Thanks again.

Comment: @AbdulJabbarWebBestow  - it would be great if you could provide the post you mention in the comment above